# What CurrentSessionContext to use with Tasks

Tags: c#-4.0, nhibernate

When using the CurrentSessionContext with Tasks, what context should be used?

I have always been using the ThreadStatic context, and I occasionally get warnings from NHProf about the same session being used in multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ThreadStatic it should be fine.  This should use a different session per thread if used properly.  I typically use something like the following to use the session context:

```
// Open a session if there is not one opened yet.
if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(sessionFactory))
{
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(sessionFactory.OpenSession());
}

var currentSession = sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
```